# Initial Segment and Isomorphisim

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be well-ordered set, $a,b \in X$.

If $(-\infty,a)\simeq(-\infty,b)$ then $a=b$.

Proof. Let $I \subseteq X$. An initial segment of a well-ordered set $X$ is a subset $I$ such that for all $a \in I$ and $x \in X$, if $x<a$ then $x \in I$.

Can you hint for this of proof?

Comment: What do you mean by isomorphism here? If, for example you take $X = \mathbb{R}$ in the standard topology and you are talking about homeomorphisms then this is not true.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise I mean isomorphism.

Comment: Please: Don't alternate in and out of MathJax several times within an expression.  Just go into MathJax where mathematical notation begins and stay in it until mathematical notation ends.  I found this: $\qquad\qquad$ ($-\infty$,a)$\simeq$($-\infty$,b)".  I changed it to $(-\infty,a)\simeq(-\infty,b)$, all between two dollar signs with no other dollar signs between them.  Without that you don't get proper spacing and you have mismatches in fonts and sometimes misalignments. $\qquad$

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Note that $X$ is assumed to be well-ordered, so if we interpret "isomorphism" as "homeomorphism" the statement is in fact true.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise So, If we take $X$ $=$ $\mathbb{R}$ in the standart topology, and we are talking about homeomorphisms then this is not true. Why? Can you prove?

Comment: @hayyam Do you see why $(-\infty, 0)\cong (-\infty, 1)$ as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$? (HINT: Consider the map $x\mapsto x+1$ . . .)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the answer is *transfinite induction*. Let me give you some hints:

Say that an element $a\in X$ is **bad** if there is some $b\in X$, $a\not= b$ such that $$(-\infty, a)\cong(-\infty, b).$$

- What do we want to show about the set $Bad$ of bad elements of $X$?
- If $Bad$ is nonempty, does it have a least element? What hypothesis on $X$ does this use?
- OK, so suppose $a$ is the least element of $Bad$. Then (by definition) there is some $b\in Bad$ such that $$(-\infty, a)\cong(-\infty, b)$$ and $b\not=a$. Then $b>a$; do you see why?
- OK, now let $i:(-\infty, a)\cong(-\infty, b)$ be an isomorphism. What can you say about $i(x)$ for $x<a$? Why is this a problem? (HINT: Can you find some $y<b$ which cannot be in the image of $i$?)